# Fragment Transaction inside a fragment with a Tabbed actionbar not working

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-fragmentactivity, fragmentpageradapter

I want to be able to replace the current fragment which is loaded via the actionbar tabs using a ViewPager with another fragment that is not connected to any tab like this

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE)
            .replace(id,frag , "VideoEdit")
            .commit();
```

however when I do this it loads the fragment all right but the tabs don't work anymore and everytime I click on a tab it just stays on this fragment. I managed to find this gist
https://gist.github.com/andreynovikov/4619215  but I'm not sure it's the same thing I'm looking for and I don't want to try it out for fear of messing up my existing code with it.

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid transitions like that.

I'll recomend to use FragmentWrapper.
One more fragment that you placed inside Tab it contains only FrameLayout as a container for other fragments. In this fragment, you could use childFragmentManager to add current Fragment and replace it with VideoEdit.